# How to insert http post data before the callback?

Tags: javascript

I built a API gateway,Function compute and Tablestore(Nosql) using Alibaba cloud to receive http post data and insert it into the a Nosql database.

While testing my code, the insert function did not invoke before the callback response. I know I should use `Async/Await`, but just don't fully understand how to use it.

I've tried `.promise()` the insert function did invoke but the callback response of the http did not invoke.
How can I put the data into my database and also gets the callback of function handler? 
Some of my code:

```
var TableStore=require('tablestore');
async function handler(event, context, callback) {
var putReq = {
    tableName: 'wifi',
    condition: new TableStore.Condition(TableStore.RowExistenceExpectation.IGNORE, null),
    primaryKey: [{ 'date':'123'  }],
    attributeColumns: [
      {'col1': JSON.stringify(data)}, // string column
      {'col2': 100},    // integer column
    ],
  };
await client.putRow(putReq,function(err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    console.log('putRow suceess: %j', data);

      callback(null, data);
    });

   const  response = Object.assign(baseresponse, {
           body: {
                status: "ok",
                body:event.body
            }
        });

   callback(null, response);


}
module.exports.handler = handler;
```

Comment: try clean up your questions. E.g. your cloud host is not a relevent piece of information, so is a lot of your overhead code.